# Find First Blank Cell Matching Specific Criteria with Matching Values

Tags: excel, indexing, find, match, vba

Yeow... That was a mouthful.

I'm setting up a log to track inventory in the office. For some items we have multiple copies of the same tool. I've gotten the VBA to track the owners with userforms and vba, but the multiple-identical-names, first-occurance, blank cell trick is proving to be too much for me.

So what you have is this:

```
Item      Serial Number     Owner
Item A     999999999
Item A     999999991
Item A     999999992
Item B     22221
Item B     22222
Item B     22223
Item C     hhhg77
Item C     hhhg78
Item C     hhhg79
```

I need the code to search for the ITEM name, gathered from ComboBox1 on the Userform, and find the first occurance of the ITEM WITHOUT an owner, (so the corresponding "OWNER" cell should be blank, and put the OWNER, gathered from ComboBox2 on the userform, in that spot.

I've been fooling around with Index & Match and VLookup and countless searches for "Finding First Row" but I've come up empty.

The ranges might be changed, so I'm hesitant to be so specific as to say search between A2:A4, so a search would be best, I think.

What I have so far is this....and it's weak, I apologize.

```
Public Sub FindBlankOwner()
    Dim MultiItem As Range
    Dim MultiOwner As Range
    Dim ITEM As String
    Dim OWNER As String
    Dim MultiSerial As Range
    Dim NO As Range

    ITEM = ComboBox1.Value
    STATUS = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ITEM, LUP, 6, False)
    OWNER = ComboBox2.Value

    Set ws = Worksheets("Owners")
    Set MultiItem = Worksheets("Owners").Range("A1:A28")
    Set MultiOwner = Worksheets("Owners").Range("C1:C28")
    Set MultiSerial = Worksheets("Owners").Range("B1:B28")

Fillin = Evaluate("INDEX(MultiOwner, MATCH(ITEM, &

'    Set FILLIN = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ITEM, (MultiItem), 0) And (Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(" ", (MultiOwner), 0))
 '   NO.Value = OWNER

    'Set FILLIN = MultiItem.Find(What:=ITEM) And MultiOwner.Find(What:="")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Search for Available Items Based on Empty Owner

*I've written some raw code for your review. You were on the right track, but with the methods below we avoid using worksheet functions and instead use VBA methods.*

---

**First thing we want to do is find the first occurrence of the user-defined `ITEM`**

**After that we check if it has an `OWNER` or not. If it does, find the next `ITEM`. If it doesn't, assign the user-defined `OWNER` to the user-defined `ITEM`.**

***I've included some message boxes for clarity and convenience of the end-user.***

---

### The Code

```
Sub FindBlankOwner()
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Owners")
    Dim ITEM As String: ITEM = ComboBox1.Value
    Dim OWNER As String: OWNER = ComboBox2.Value
    Dim BlankOwnerFound As Boolean: BlankOwnerFound = False
    Dim firstResult As String
    Dim ItemRange As Range: Set ItemRange = ws.Range("A:A").Find(What:=ITEM, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)

    If Not ItemRange Is Nothing Then
        firstResult = ItemRange.Address
        Do
            If Trim(ItemRange.Offset(0, 2).Value) = "" Then
                ItemRange.Offset(0, 2).Value = OWNER
                BlankOwnerFound = True
            Else
                Set ItemRange = ws.Range("A:A").FindNext(ItemRange)
            End If
        Loop While Not ItemRange Is Nothing And ItemRange.Address <> firstResult And BlankOwnerFound = False
    Else: MsgBox "No results for " & ITEM & " found.", vbCritical, "Cannot Find " & ITEM
    End If

    If BlankOwnerFound = True Then
        MsgBox OWNER & " has checked out " & ITEM & " with Serial Number " & ItemRange.Offset(0, 1).Value & ".", _
               vbOKOnly, ITEM & " Check-Out Successful"
    Else: MsgBox "No available " & ITEM & " in inventory.", vbCritical, "All " & ITEM & " are checked out."
    End If
End Sub
```

---

***NOTE:*** I haven't tested this code aside from reading it to myself to ensure it makes sense. There may be a couple errors (hopefully not) and if you can't solve them, please don't hesitate to let me know so we can work on it together. Let me know if this works for you :)

Comment: Thank you!!! Wow, That is a thing of beauty that I could never have created. I was somewhat on the same track when you replied. Find the item. Find the owner. If the owner is NOT empty, move down one row until you find an empty owner. 

It was getting stuck on the 
firstResult = ItemRange.Address bit...but now it's going through. It is not, however, adding the owner to the OWNER cell.

Comment: So the code runs now, without error, but it's not placing the owner in the OWNER cell? The message box come up properly? You see the line where it's doing that right? I assumed that your spreadsheet was setup similar to how it is in your question. Is it in fact 2 columns to the right of the ITEM Column?

Comment: Ahhh can't believe I did that... I've changed the code to fix the problem. It was where `firstResult` was declared. It should be a String, not a Range. See if the code works properly for you now. :)

Comment: Works brilliantly. Thank you so much. I wish I had your talent.

Comment: If I have answered your question, would you mind hitting the check mark to accept this as the answer? It's my reward for being useful to you :)